# Functional way to loop over nested list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion, imperative-programming

I was given a question to compare two trees. Something like below:

```
case class Node(elem:String, child:List[Node])
```

In order to compare each elements of the trees, I have following functions:

```
def compare(n1:Node, n2:Node): Boolean {
   if(n1.elem == n2.elem){
      return compare(n1.child, n2.child)
   }
}

def compare(c1:List[Node], c2:List[Node]): Boolean {
    while (c1.notEmpty) {
       //filter, map etc call function above to compare the element recursively
    }
}
```

Basically algorithm is for each elements in n1, we are checking for a match in n2. I was told that this is very imperative way and not functional way. What would be a functional way to achieve this behaviour. In other words, how do we remove while loop when comparing the list of children?

Comment: Do you need to compare every element in the first list with every element in the second list? Or just both first elements, both seconds elements and so on?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare two unordered children to see weather one list contains exactly the same elements as the other all the way down to the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to compare every element of the first list with every element of the second list. The following code achieves this. It gets rid of the `while` loop via a tail-recursion.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def cmp(a:Int, b:Int) = a > b

@tailrec
def compare(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): Boolean = xs match {
    case Nil => true
    case head :: tail if ys.forall(x => cmp(head, x)) => compare(tail, ys)
    case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider zipping both lists and using `forall` which holds `true` only if each and every predicate it processes evaluates to `true`; for instance like this,

```
def compare(c1: List[Node], c2: List[Node]): Boolean = 
  (c1.sorted zip c2.sorted).forall(c => compare(c._1,c._2))
```

Note that `forall` will halt the evaluations as it encounters the first `false`. Cases of unequal length lists of nodes may be tackled with `zipAll` by defining an `EmptyNode` class for padding length differences; also both lists empty may compare to `true`.

**Update**
Sorted lists of nodes for soundness following comment by @JohnB.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems like the OP wants to compare every node in the first list to every other node in the second list. Your code would not achieve that, am I right?

Comment: With the zipAll and a 'emptynode' instance to pad any missing cases it would compare them all. The issue I see however, is that you could consider them equal if they had all the same nodes but different ordering, so sorting first or converting both lists to sets and doing set1.forall(c => s2.contains(c)) and the inverse.

Comment: @JohnB agree, Many Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Um, I think Seq already has equals that compares all elements. You could use `List.corresponds` for other predicates. BTW, OP said children are unordered, but that doesn't sound normal. (sorry, I saw the OP comment "exactly the same elements", which isn't the general compare.)

Comment: zip won't work in my case, I need to compare each element of outer list to each element in inner list. Combining nodes at same position won't work.